# How do I go about colouring visited links?

Tags: color, website-design, color-theory, hyperlink

I'm making a website for my software company. Originally, I made the "visited" colour for links a darker version of the primary link colour. Looking back, I decided that the dark blue colour was too hard to read, so I changed it to a light grey colour instead. I feel that the light grey is too similar to the text colour and didn't feel like a clickable link. I would like to know some best practices for colouring hyperlinks.

Comment: Every web site is different, with different color schemes and visuals. I don't think there's any specific "universal best practices" for such things. Text based links would follow standard text practices - readability, contrast, etc. However, in terms  of visited link color usage, that's really site-specific.

Comment: You could argue the best practice is the default colour, and users are used to seeing it. 
 Although I hate the default colour.